# http calls not completing on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from an API using `get("https://myAPI.com")` but while it works fine on iOS it just doesn't work on Android.

I've tried adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

To my AndroidManifest.xml file but it still doesn't work.

Trying to make any kind of http request gives me the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: 
Failed host lookup: 'myAPI.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

Does anyone have any clue what I can do to get it working?

ENV infos:

flutter --version:

```
Flutter 1.15.4-pre.188 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter
Framework • revision 444b13b895 (3 days ago) • 2020-02-26 16:04:35 -0800
Engine • revision ecabc10376
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.10.0 4189237330)
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.4-pre.188, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale
    en-BR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Is this an emulator? If so, can you connect to the internet using the web browser in it? This may be a simple connection problem.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus yes and no. not sure how to solve it tho. iOS emulator is working fine. is there any configuration I have to do so internet connection is available to android emulators as well?

Comment: Sometimes a simple reboot of the emulator fixes it (hold the virtual power button). One thing that would surely work is to create a brand new emulator device.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, insecure HTTP connections are disabled by default on iOS and Android.
Please follow these steps if you face issue while making network calls..

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml file in your android directory of flutter project and add these lines.

   ```
   //step 1 add this line outside application tag 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
   //step 2 add this line in application attribute. 
   <application
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
   >
    //step 3 add this line inside application opening and closing tags
   <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
   android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/> <== Add this portion
   </application>
   ```
2. create a file in res/xml/network_security_config.xml.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <trust-anchors>
       <certificates src="system" />
     </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
   </network-security-config>
   ```

Now your app will make requests for all types of connections. For additional information on this topic [visit official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).